new NativeEventEmitter() requires a non-null argument
I am encountering an error when trying to register the foreground service using ReactNativeForegroundService from the @supersami/rn-foreground-service library. The same code works correctly on Android, but I am facing issues on iOS.
Code:
import ReactNativeForegroundService from "@supersami/rn-foreground-service";

const config = {
  config: {
    alert: true,
    onServiceErrorCallBack: function () {
      console.warn('[ReactNativeForegroundService] onServiceErrorCallBack', arguments);
    },
  }
};

ReactNativeForegroundService.register(config);

Error:
ERROR  Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes
WARN  Module ReactNativeEventEmitter requires main queue setup since it overrides `init` but doesn't implement `requiresMainQueueSetup`. In a future release React Native will default to initializing all native modules on a background thread unless explicitly opted-out of.
LOG  Running "Cerge" with {"rootTag":21,"initialProps":{}}

Environment:

React Native version: "0.71.19"

Library version: "^2.1.1"

JS Engine: Hermes

Platform: iOS


Steps to Reproduce:

Install the @supersami/rn-foreground-service library.

Use the ReactNativeForegroundService.register(config) method in the code as shown above.

Run the app on iOS with Hermes enabled.


Expected Behavior: The service should register without errors.
Actual Behavior: The error new NativeEventEmitter() requires a non-null argument occurs, and the warning about requiresMainQueueSetup appears.
Additional Context: This issue appears to be related to how the NativeEventEmitter is being initialized with a null or undefined argument. The warning suggests the module may need to implement requiresMainQueueSetup.
I tried installing the latest version of the @supersami/rn-foreground-service library and registering the service using both the configuration method and the simplified approach like this:
ReactNativeForegroundService.register({id: 144});
However, nothing worked, and I still received the same error.
